# Download cognos reports from Java via REST API

Tags: java, rest, cognos

For a particular functionality implementation, I need to download a chart(even a report would do) from the cognos server from my Java Code. I am unable to find efficient ways of doing the same, I could find few resources(links below) but none of them seem to work. Is there a way to download cognos reports from Java via REST API?

[DZONE](https://dzone.com/articles/cognos-ibm-sdk-with-java)
[MashUp Service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dg_cms.10.2.2.doc/c_raas_rest.html#raas_rest)

Comment: Please define `none of them seems to work`. Post relevant code, preferably a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What errors do you get? Post stacktraces or tell us why it's not what you expect.

Comment: Hi @jannis, both the solutions require adding dependency for Cognos SDK which might not be the best possible solution. Furthermore the dependencies are not available in maven public repository.

Comment: Did you try any of these endpoints: [reportData](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dg_cms.10.2.2.doc/r_rest_res_reportdata.html#rest_res_reportData), [pagedReportData](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dg_cms.10.2.2.doc/r_dg_raas_rest_ref_paged_reportdata.html#dg_raas_rest_ref_paged_reportdata)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the Cognos Mashup Service (CMS).  CMS requires a license to use the Cognos SDK.

You didn't specify which version of Cognos, so I can't direct you to the exact documentation.